# Code obfuscation and debugging

Tags: sdk, obfuscation

I am creating a SDK and obfuscating the code through proguard/dexguard but I am not sure how my developers can debug the code if the code is obfuscated. Not obfuscating the SDK code is not an option.

Code obfuscation and debugging don't seem to work parallely unless I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask DexGuard to print a mapping file. This is achieved by including the option -printmapping "mapping.txt" in the DexGuard configuration file. Together with this mapping and a stacktrace you can use the retrace.jar tool, included with DexGuard, to de-obfuscate the stacktrace and debug the SDK.

All the information on how to do this can be found in the docs/ directory shipped with DexGuard.

Cheers,

Dario

Comment: Actually, I was looking for suggestions on how the developers that use my SDK will debug their apps that are built using my SDK. If they want to step through the code, they will be looking at obfuscated code - of course some of the public interfaces are not obfuscated. What you suggested works for me as the guy who built the SDK to de-obfuscate the code using the mapping.txt.

Comment: Unless you're willing to share the mapping file, nobody can debug using unobfuscated code. DexGuard removes all debugging information (sourcefile names and linenumbers etc)